# printf in shell script

Tags: shell

I have below printf statement in shell script

```
printf "%-60s   read-successful %-30s$value1 \n" "${value2}" >> output1
```

output expected:

```
value2      read-successful  value1
```

I am getting correct output when value2 is not IP address but when its IP output is not as expected.

when i tried with set -x.It shows me below

```
printf '%-60s   read-successful %-30s$ \n'  $'10.63.112.56\r'
```

Comment: It looks like you read the IP address from a file with Windows-style line-endings (CR LF).

Comment: @Biffen What changes should i do to print only IP address

Comment: @Biffen tried this but no luck ```printf "%-60s   read-successful %-30s$value1 \n" "${value2}|tr -d '\r'" >> output1```

Comment: `${value2%$'\r'}` is the correct formulation. Or `${testVar//$'\r'}`. Checking the proposed duplicate it does show answers that work in this context (and don't have a pipeline's inefficiency)

Comment: @AWS_Beginner, btw, while I don't recommend it, if you _did_ want to use a `tr`-based approach for some reason, that might look like `printf "%-60s   read-successful %-30s$value1 \n" "$(tr -d <<<"${value2}")"` (though really, `value1` should have its own `%s` placeholder and be a separate argument rather than substituted into the format string)